# Disable Client Side Routing in Gatsby

Tags: amazon-s3, gatsby

Is it possible to disable client side routing in Gatsby?

I'm using Gatsby to generate a static site which only has one page and will be served from AWS/S3. I'm running into an issue caused by Gatsby removing the object suffix from the URL (https://s3.amazonaws.com/top-bucket/sub-bucket/index.html becomes https://s3.amazonaws.com/top-bucket/sub-bucket/) after the page and the Gatsby runtime loads. This issue does not happen if I disable JavaScript, so I'm pretty certain it's caused by Gatsby's use of React/Reach Router.

Is there any way to disable this behavior? I know I can probably setup a redirect on S3 to handle the request to the bucket, but I'd prefer to do this at the application level, if possible.

Comment: How are you linking to that URL from gatsby?

Comment: @DerekNguyen I'm not doing any linking. The site is a single page and there is no navigation whatsoever.

Comment: My bad, I misread your post. Are you using `pathPrefix`? I notice that it removes index.html path from my url, though without it my assets break. If you do have it & turning it off resolve the issue, consider modifying webpack configuration to add a `publicPath` for your assets?

Comment: You also might be interested in this plugin, though it doesn't handle the issue at application level like you prefer https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-s3/

Comment: @DerekNguyen Yes, I am using `pathPrefix`. I wonder why that would result in this behavior? Do you have links to any relevant documentation? I'm guessing if I had to set `publicPath`, I'd do it through, `onCreateWebpackConfig`?

Comment: Yeah, I think you’d add it there & add it to `build-javascript ` stage https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/add-custom-webpack-config/

Comment: I also find it unexpected for pathPrefix to modify index path, maybe it’s being handled by reach router and that’s default behavior? Let me know if that is indeed the source of your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hack and may not work in anyone else's application or break with future releases of Gatsby, but I was able to prevent this redirect by setting `window.page.path = window.location.pathname;` in gatsby-browser.js. This short circuits a conditional check in [production-app.js](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/packages/gatsby/cache-dir/production-app.js#L68-L69), which attempts to "make the canonical path match the actual path" and results in the (IMO) unexpected behavior referenced above.

Comment: As expected, this workaround broke after a recent release of Gatbsy. See [this](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/4337) issue which covers some alternative approaches.

Answer (score 1):

this issue is pretty old but hope it helps someone, I used this plugin: https://github.com/wardpeet/gatsby-plugin-static-site

`npm install @wardpeet/gatsby-plugin-static-site --save`

And just added it in gatsby-config.js

```
plugins: [{
  `@wardpeet/gatsby-plugin-static-site`,
}]
```

Client side routing was then disabled!